# Streams usage in Java

Tags: java, stream

could you please advice what Java I/O Streams can be used for? Every of them which is in standard Java 5 or Java 6 I/O API.

For example FileReader and FileWriter are used for reading and writing files.
StringReader and StringWriter are used for reading and writing strings in memory.
ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream used for Serialization.

If you know there is somewhere such table please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Java I/O Streams article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Streams/ProgIOStreams/) in Java Reference, tables in section "Specialized Descendent Stream Classes"

Comment: Thank you. Despite not all of the streams are listed. It contains the table where written what's for and when they can be used.

Answer (score 4):

The official Java tutorial has a whole chapter dedicated to streams:

[Lesson: Basic I/O (The Java™ Tutorials > Essential Classes)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

[Data Streams (The Java™ Tutorials > Essential ...](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/datastreams.html)

Answer (score 2):

The [javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html) for the java.io package would be a good place to start.